# Realtime ffmpeg shell output PHP

Tags: php, linux, shell, ffmpeg

Alright, I've been fighting this problem for a few days. Works fine on my local windows machine but, can't seem to get it to work on my CentOS server. My script grabs the duration of the video being converted and also grabs the current seconds it has processed inside of ffmpeg. However, it is only grabbing the "input file" of the ffmpeg output and stopping there. I have tried using both pipes (STDOUT [1] & STDERR [2]) for some reason ffmpeg likes to output on the STDERR pipe. Weird.

```
$filename = "somefilename.tmp";
$descriptor = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
    2 => array("pipe", "w")
);

$ffmpeg = "ffmpeg -i /var/www/spotloader/videos/flipped/tmp/".$file."_comb.ts -vcodec mpeg2video -acodec pcm_s16le -pix_fmt yuv422p -vtag xdvb -b:v 13000k -r 30000/1001 /var/www/spotloader/videos/flipped/tmp/".$file.".mov";

//open the process
$process = proc_open($ffmpeg, $descriptor, $pipes, NULL, $_ENV);

//if the process opened
if ( is_resource( $process ) == true )
{
    //get process status
    $procStatus = proc_get_status( $process );

    //if its running, let node know
    if ( $procStatus['running'] )
    {
        //nodejs socket, nothing wrong here
        $this->_sendSocket('converting', array('filename' => str_replace('.tmp', '', $file)));
    }

    //while the process is running
    while( $procStatus['running'] === true )
    {
        //there is output in the pipe
        if ( !feof( $pipes[1] ) )
        {
            //get the output
            $data = fgets($pipes[1], 128);
            //match the outputs duration and save it.
            if(preg_match('/Duration:\s([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/', $data, $matches)) 
            {
                static $duration;
                $duration = $this->_convertToSeconds($matches[1]);
            }
        
            //match the outputs current encoding time
            if(preg_match('/time=([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/', $data, $matches)) 
            {
                //convert to seconds works fine, so it is not included.
                $curTime = $this->_convertToSeconds($matches[1]);
                //nodejs socket, nothing wrong here
                $this->_sendSocket('update', array('percent' => round( ($curTime / $duration) * 100), 'filename' => str_replace('.tmp', '', $file)));
            }
        }

        //update process status
        $procStatus = proc_get_status( $process );
    }

    //nodejs socket, nothing wrong here
    $this->_sendSocket('converted', array('percent' => 100, 'filename' => str_replace('.tmp', '', $file)));
}
```

FFMPEG output I receive using the PHP code above

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 10 2013 15:14:14 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 
--mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl 
--enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads 
--enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv 
--enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut 
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg 
--enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis 
--enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid 
--extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions 
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' 
--disable-stripping
libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mpegts @ 0x243c620] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000 microseconds
Input #0, mpegts, from '/var/www/spotloader/videos/flipped/tmp/Wildlife10.tmp_comb.ts':
Duration: 00:00:02.02, start: 1.389978, bitrate: 227018 kb/s
Program 1
Metadata:
  service_name    : Service01
  service_provider: FFmpeg
Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL+FR), s16p, 128 kb/s
```

FFMPEG output I'm expecting the "time=00:00:00" towards the end is what I need to capture in realtime. This is taken by running the FFMPEG command directly in the shell.

```
ffmpeg version 1.2.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 10 2013 15:14:14 with gcc 4.4.6 (GCC) 20120305 (Red Hat 4.4.6-4)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 
--mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl 
--enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads 
--enable-x11grab --enable-vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv 
--enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut 
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg 
--enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis 
--enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid 
--extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions 
-fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' 
--disable-stripping
  libavutil      52. 18.100 / 52. 18.100
  libavcodec     54. 92.100 / 54. 92.100
  libavformat    54. 63.104 / 54. 63.104
  libavdevice    54.  3.103 / 54.  3.103
  libavfilter     3. 42.103 /  3. 42.103
  libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
  libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
  libpostproc    52.  2.100 / 52.  2.100
[mpegts @ 0x10c9620] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000 microseconds
Input #0, mpegts, from '/var/www/spotloader/videos/flipped/tmp/Wildlife10.tmp_comb.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:02.02, start: 1.389978, bitrate: 227018 kb/s
  Program 1
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: mpeg2video (4:2:2) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 59.94 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, 1 channels (FL+FR), s16p, 128 kb/s
Channel layout 'stereo' with 2 channels does not match specified number of channels 1: ignoring specified channel layout
Output #0, mov, to '/var/www/spotloader/videos/flipped/tmp/Wildlife10.tmp.mov':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf54.63.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: mpeg2video (xdvb / 0x62766478), yuv422p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 13000 kb/s, 30k tbn, 29.97 tbc
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mpeg2video -> mpeg2video)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (mp2 -> pcm_s16le)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:1 chl:1 channels (FL+FR) to rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:2 chl:stereo
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:2 chl:stereo to rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:1 chl:mono
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:1 chl:mono to rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:2 chl:stereo
Input stream #0:0 frame changed from size:1920x1080 fmt:yuv422p to size:1280x720 fmt:yuv422p0
Input stream #0:1 frame changed from rate:48000 fmt:s16p ch:2 chl:stereo to rate:44100 fmt:s16p ch:2 chl:stereo
frame=  741 fps= 52 q=2.6 size=   43866kB time=00:00:24.65 bitrate=14573.5kbits/s dup=5 drop=0
```

Any ideas? What needs changing from the switch from Windows to CentOS?

**EDIT:**
I got this to work using [popen](https://www.php.net/popen) instead. It also reduced my code. If anyone else does have a solution go ahead and post it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## heres something

This was from a project i was working on a while ago. I think it's pretty close to what you want. Be warned it's a bit buggy and not very secure

*ffmpeTest.php*

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Video Uploader</h2>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="file" required id="upload"  name="file"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Upload video" id="upload" name="upload"/> 
</form>

<?
ini_set('memory_limit', '1000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1000M');
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');


if(isset($_POST['upload'])){

$ffmpeg = '/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/1.2.1/bin/ffmpeg';//path to ffmpeg    

$origVideo =  $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$newVideo = "videos/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($origVideo, $newVideo);
$time = time();
  
$command1 = $ffmpeg.' -i "'.$newVideo.'" videos/'.$time.'.flv ';
shell_exec(sprintf('%s > videos/block.txt 2>&1 &', $command1));   
}
?>

<div id="load"></div>
<script>  

$('#thumb').load(function(){
setInterval(function() {
          $('#load').load('http://localhost/Playground/ffmpeLoader.php                           ffmpeLoader.php');
}, 600);
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

*ffmpeloader.php*

```
<?
$content = @file_get_contents('videos/block.txt');

if($content){
    //get duration of source
    preg_match("/Duration: (.*?), start:/", $content, $matches);

    $rawDuration = $matches[1];

    //rawDuration is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawDuration));
    $duration = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $duration += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $duration += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //get the time in the file that is already encoded
    preg_match_all("/time=(.*?) bitrate/", $content, $matches);

    $rawTime = array_pop($matches);

    //this is needed if there is more than one match
    if (is_array($rawTime)){$rawTime = array_pop($rawTime);}

    //rawTime is in 00:00:00.00 format. This converts it to seconds.
    $ar = array_reverse(explode(":", $rawTime));
    $time = floatval($ar[0]);
    if (!empty($ar[1])) $time += intval($ar[1]) * 60;
    if (!empty($ar[2])) $time += intval($ar[2]) * 60 * 60;

    //calculate the progress
    $progress = round(($time/$duration) * 100);
    echo "<progress id='p' max='100' value='" . $progress . "'></progress><span> ".$progress."%</span>";

    
}
if($progress == 100){
    

        echo '<p> Done!</p>';
    }
?>
```